# Local Wordpress using POW.cx, assets return Rack Legacy Error

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, rack, pow.cx

I'm using POW.cx to run Wordpress sites locally with the help of rack-legacy.

When going to the domain I've set (eg *powwordpress.dev*), it renders the PHP content - I can see all the text and fields in *powwordpress.dev/install.php*.

However, it does not render any of the assets (CSS, JS, etc), and when I try to go look at the file in the browser, such as *powwordpress.dev/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0*, I receive this:

```
Rack::Legacy::ExecutionError at /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
Rack::Legacy::ExecutionError

Ruby: /Users/HomeMac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4.1.1/gems/rack-legacy-0.9.1/lib/rack/legacy/cgi.rb: in run, line 77
Web: GET powwordpress.dev/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
```

Here is my config.ru;

```
require 'rack/showexceptions'
require 'rack-legacy'

use Rack::ShowExceptions
use Rack::Legacy::Index
use Rack::Legacy::Php
use Rack::Legacy::Cgi
run Rack::File.new Dir.getwd
```

Any idea how I can fix this pathing / rack-legacy issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing a few things thanks to this gem - https://github.com/firmhouse/presspass

- **require 'rack/showexceptions'** to just **require 'rack'**
- removed **use Rack::ShowExceptions**
- removed **use Rack::Legacy::Cgi**

My final config.ru file;

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack-legacy'

use Rack::Legacy::Index
use Rack::Legacy::Php
run Rack::File.new Dir.getwd
```